# Could not create Image Space with Image file while Building AOSP code

Tags: android, build

I am trying to build AOSP code (Version 5.1) on chromium source code. When I am trying build I am getting these errors.

Could not create image space with image file '/system/framework/boot.art'. Attempting to fall back to imageless running. Error was: Failed to generate image '/data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/system@framework@boot.art': Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --image=/data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/system@framework@boot.art

I tried the solution from the link but not working for me
[how to solve W/art : Could not create image space with image file '/system/framework/boot.art' while trying to port Android Lollipop on Arndale Board?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209977/how-to-solve-w-art-could-not-create-image-space-with-image-file-system-frame)

Please help me